# bottlepy hello world app not working

Tags: python, bottle

I am quite new to bottlepy, started with hello world but cant get it working.

this is the code.

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

and I am pointing my browser to http://hostname:8080/ or http://ipaddress:8080/

but i always get error saying could not connect.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/hello`

Comment: Hi J.F. Sebastian, sorry i forgot to mentioned that, i tried that as well and still no luck.

Comment: What's the output you get when running this code?

Comment: If anyone is still having trouble with this try adding "#!/usr/bin/python" to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add

```
@route('/')
```

before `@route('/hello')`, then you can visit `http://localhost:8080`.

If it still does not work, I think you need to try to put `bottle.py` lib file into your project root dir either.